# Short exact sequences and finite injective dimension

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra

Say that $0 \to M \to N \to L \to 0$ is a short exact sequence of modules in a Noetherian local ring and that inj dim$(M)$, inj dim$(N) < \infty$. Does this imply that $L$ also have finite injective dimension?

I know that the injective dimensions of $M$ and $N$ are the same, and I know there is a complex map between them by the comparison theorem, but I was stuck there.

Comment: Take a minimal injective resolution for both $M$ and $L$. Build from them an injective resolution for $N$: what can you say? Will it have zero homology from some point on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the short exact sequence $0\to M\to N\to L\to 0$ gives the long exact sequence $\cdots\to \mathrm{Ext}^i(A,M)\to \mathrm{Ext}^i(A,N)\to \mathrm{Ext}^i(A,L)\to \mathrm{Ext}^{i+1}(A,M)\to\cdots$. This doesn't need the ring to be Noetherian or local, and also shows that if two of the three have finite injective dimension, the third does as well.